# MSSQL xml path() query not working in PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, for-xml-path

The following query works fine when executed in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio but when I run the query through php I get no output (nothing past the mssql_query() gets rendered).

If i remove `for xml path('')` from the SQL query and again run in php, now everything past the mssql_query() gets rendered).

Does anybody know of any issues with xml path('') and PHP or whether im doing something wrong.

```
SELECT DISTINCT x1.AcademicYearID, x1.RefNo, x1.Source, x1.Surname, x1.FirstForename, x1.Heard,convert(VARCHAR, x1.Date, 121) as Date, Notes, School, 
(SELECT DISTINCT x2.Subject + ', ' as 'data()' from [db].[dbo].[vCC_Mkt_Enquiries] x2 WHERE x1.RefNo = x2.RefNo AND x1.Source = x2.Source for xml path('')) as Subject 
FROM [db].[dbo].[vCC_Mkt_Enquiries] x1 
WHERE x1.AcademicYearID = '13/14'
```

**PHP**

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT x1.AcademicYearID, x1.RefNo, x1.Source, x1.Surname, x1.FirstForename, x1.Heard,convert(VARCHAR, x1.Date, 121) as Date, Notes, School, 
(SELECT DISTINCT x2.Subject + ', ' as 'data()' from [db].[dbo].[vCC_Mkt_Enquiries] x2 WHERE x1.RefNo = x2.RefNo AND x1.Source = x2.Source for xml path('')) as Subject 
FROM [db].[dbo].[vCC_Mkt_Enquiries] x1 
WHERE x1.AcademicYearID = '$year'";

$internal_events = mssql_query($sql, $connection) or die ("Error in query: $sql. ".mssql_error());
```

**Please NOTE: The following or die error never gets rendered.**

```
or die ("Error in query: $sql. ".mssql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to retype the returned xml type into e.g. nvarchar. Just like this:

```
DECLARE @XML XML

SET @XML = (

SELECT something 
FROM sometable
FOR XML PATH('items')

)

SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @XML)
```